# How to check if variable is 'not defined' (not simply `undefined`)

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if a variable is `not defined`, excluding variables assigned to `undefined`, without `try/catch`.

I know about `typeof variable`, but that does not fit what I want.

For example :

```
let a;
console.log(typeof a === typeof b); // outputs true

console.log(a); // outputs 'undefined'
console.log(b); // throws error 'b is not defined'
```

What I would like to have is beeing able to tell the difference between not-defined variables and the ones whose value is `undefined`, without having to use a `try/catch`.

My use case (from comments) is:

> I would like to see the difference in a function call between a parameter ommitted and set at undefined. And also in general if it was possible

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use window.hasOwnProperty("var"), like so:

Don't know if this works in all cases though...

You could also try using the "this" keyword instead of "window" to focus the "hasOwnProperty" function on the current scope.

```js
var a;

console.log("Is a declared? "+window.hasOwnProperty("a"));
console.log("type of a: "+typeof(a));
console.log("Is b declared? "+window.hasOwnProperty("b"));
console.log("type of b: "+typeof(b));
```

Comment: Well they could replace "window" with whichever scope is needed, but yeah it's not a perfect solution by any means. Still, hasOwnProperty might be somewhere towards the solution OP is looking for

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it will output false it you replace `var` by `let`

Comment: @Archer sorry if my comment seemed rude. The way I interpretted your comment was that I refused to give a use case. I am not a native english speaker so that might be my bad.

Comment: @Seblor Thanks - no worries.  Just trying to keep it nice, but it turns out there was no need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find omitted parameters using  `arguments`

```
function f(a,b) {
    switch (arguments.length){
        case 1:{
            console.log("b omitted");
            return;
        }
        case 0:{
            console.log("a and b omitted");
            return;
        }
    }
}

f();//a and b omitted
f(1);//b omitted
```

Comment: I will accept your answer if I don't get a working general solution (outside of a function) soon. Thanks

Comment: While your question is perfectly valid, can I know why you needed to know the difference between those. Also, you should know that `undefined` is a type and well as a value. And this value is assigned to both an uninitialized variable as well as unpassed function argument. ( `arguments` array (or any js array) can be considered an array of infinite length with few explicit value and rest `undefined`. ). Since both are having exact same value, you can't distinguish between them, at least by their values.

Comment: It was as much to fix an issue I had (but I solved the root issue meanwhile), as a simple question to which I had no answer

Answer (score -1):

Use *arguments*:

```
> function f(a,b,c) { console.log(arguments) }
> f(1,2,3)
Prints:
  { '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3 }

> f(1,2)
Prints:
  { '0': 1, '1': 2 }

> f(1,2,undefined)
Prints:
  { '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': undefined }
```